# get a total of jquery's .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery's .each() to iterate over a group of li's. I need a total of all the li's matched. Is the only way to create a count variable outside the .each() and increment this inside the .each()? It doesn't seem very elegant.

```
var count;
$('#accordion li').each(function() {
    ++count;
});
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Two options:

```
$('#accordion li').size(); // the jQuery way
$('#accordion li').length; // the Javascript way, which jQuery uses
```

Since jQuery calls length under the hood, it's faster to use that instead of the size() call.

Comment: The jQuery docs actually recommend using `length`, not `size()`: see the comment at http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Yeah I just didn't like the repition of the jquery selector...once for the each() and then again for the size(). I've just assigned $('#accordion li') to a var now and called that twice.

Comment: Then, what's the use of .size() if it uses .length? Is there any advantage?

Answer (score 9):

Well, I just saw this question, and you already accepted an answer, but I'm going to leave one anyway.

The point of the question seems to be concerned with incrementing a counter.

The fact is that jQuery's `.each()` method takes care of this for you. The first parameter for `.each()` *is* an incrementing counter, so you don't need to do it yourself.

```
$('#accordian li').each(function(index) {
       // index has the count of the current iteration
    console.log( index );
});
```

So as you can see, there is an elegant solution built in for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I actually need the total count. I know index gives me the incrementing counter but I need the total count of all matched list items.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#accordion li').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the best way to do this is as follows:  firstly map the wrapped set to a variable so you never have to do the sizzle dom lookup again:

```
var $myListItems = $('#accordian li');
```

*Note: my preference is to put $ at the beginning of any vars that are a jQuery wrapped set, hence $myListItems as opposed to myListItems*

Then set a var outside the each function that has the length of the wrapped set:

```
var myLength = $myListItems.length;
```

*Note the lack of a $ here as the var is not a jQuery object.*

Now run the each function with a variable for the index.

```
$myListItems.each(function(index){
    // myLength has the length
    // index has the current, 0 based index.
});
```

You now have what you've asked for in the OP with only one look up and so need to fumble in the each function with having to know the contents of the wrapped set just to know the length of it.  the beauty of this over a counter is that on every iteration of the each you already know the length.

Comment: agree we need to not look up the dom twice to get the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
const count = $('#accordion li').each(function() {
    // Do something
}).length;
```

It works because [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) returns a [jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) which has a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big issues, which I have not found a fix for yet, is if you have two sets of the same thing you will iterate through.

For instance, 2 table heads that you are iterating through number of column headers. If you use length on ( *$item.children().find('thead tr th').each...* ) for your each clause and you have 2 tables it will double the amount of your length that you are trying to walk through potentially [5 column headers in each table will return length of 10].

You could do both on a id name and have those different but if adding dynamically then this can become a headache.

The only way I found once inside the foreach is to use $(this):

```
$item.children().find('thead tr th').each(function(i, th) {
  // I am working with a table but div could be used, or something else. 
  // I have 2 tables with 5 column headers, the below len return
  var len = $(this).closest('table').find('thead tr th').length;
  if (i < len) {
    // ...your code here
  }
});
```